Mapstruct handling of Interfaces/Parents and Generics
I am trying to solve an issue with Mapstruct. I have a record A which implements an interface B which itself extends another interface. The idea being that B corresponds to a getter of A's property, and B itself is a specific type of a more generic property.
public interface C<S extends Card> {
     S card();
}

(Card here is an interface)
public interface B extends C<CardM> {
     CardM card();
}

(CardM is a record implementing Card)
public record A(     
    CardM card
) implements B {} 

In my mapper class I have defined 2 mappers, one to map A to another class (BO) and a mapper to map CardM to a similar object in BO (CardBo which is a class and doesn't implement the Card interface). So I have a single class that contains these two methods :
@BeanMapping(ignoreByDefault = true)
@Mapping(target = "card", source = "card")
public abstract BO mapBo(A request);

and
@BeanMapping(ignoreByDefault = true)
@Mapping(<... a bunch of mappers here not relevant to the question>)
protected abstract CardBo mapCard(CardM card);

I expected that, when mapstruct generates the mappers, mapBo would use mapCard to map CardM to BO's CardBo. Instead it generates a new method mapping the top interface C to Card and uses that:
    @Override
public BO mapBo(A request) {
    if ( request == null ) {
        return null;
    }
    BO bo = new BO();

    bo .setCard( cardToCard( request.card() ) );
}

    

protected CardBo cardToCard(C card) {
    if ( card == null ) {
        return null;
    }

    CardBo card1 = new CardBo();

    return card1;
}

I have tried using the qualifiedBy="name" to force the use of my mapCard, and I know that I could solve the issue using the expression "java(mapCard(...))" as well, but my question is why is Mapstruct not using my mapper automatically? request.card() doesn't return C but CardM and the signatures match. It seems like an issue with generics and hierarchy.
I have solved the issue by forcing the call as such :
@Mapping(target = "card", expression = "java(mapCard(request.card()))")

but apart from using my mapper directly with the expression option, is there another way to solve this (using qualifiedByName doesnt work, I tried)?

Have you tried annotating the class that contains the mapCard mapping with the uses attribute? Such as this:
@Mapper(uses = BoMapper.class)
public interface CardMapper {

  @BeanMapping(ignoreByDefault = true)
  @Mapping(<... a bunch of mappers here not relevant to the question>)
  protected abstract Card mapCard(CardM card);
}

With BoMapper the mapper class that contains the mapBo method.

The mapBo method is in the same class as the mapCard method, so this would not solve my issue.

I'm trying to replicate the error, but I noticed one thing: you say that Card is an interface; because of this, how can mapstruct create a Card card1 = new Card(); statement? Using your mapping code, I got an error telling that "The return type Card is an abstract class or interface. Provide a non abstract / non interface result type or a factory method." Is BO's Card different from the Card interface?

Update: I also tried to use another specific Card type, used as an attribute of the BO record; in this case, the mapper impl is created correctly. Moreover, I don't understand how is called the cardToCard since it requires a C parameter while request.card() returns a CardM that is not a subtype of C. Perhaps I am missing something of the original code in my own implementation.

I'm trying to recreate the error as well. I simplified the example in the question since the actual code is company code which I cant share. However in my simplified version the mapping is done correctly. Theres a lot of generics and interface implementations in my real code which may be confusing map struc

As for your question, the Card that is the result of the mapping is indeed another type (specific to BO and a class). I agree that its confusing since both the interface and the card have the same name. I'll update the question to reflect that (and also, the BO.Card doesn't implement the Card interface)
